# Returning Object with List but Filtering List Using WHERE

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have an Object, `MyRoot` with a DateTime and a List.  How would I use the WHERE statement to narrow down the list, but still also return the `MyRoot` and the List with the narrowed down results?

Here's my classes:

```
public class MyRoot 
{
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public MyRates Rates { get; set; }
}

public class MyRates
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Rate { get; set; }
}
```

Sample Code:

```
var rateList = new List<MyRates>() { 
   new MyRate { Type = "A", Program = "ABC", Rate = "1.0" },
   new MyRate { Type = "B", Program = "DEF", Rate = "1.5" },
   new MyRate { Type = "B", Program = "XYZ", Rate = "2.5" },
};

var myRoot = new MyRoot { RatesAsOf = "2016-11-09", Rates = ratesList };
```

Problem: I cannot figure out how I can return the `myRoot` object WHERE the `rateList` has `Type = "B"`  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The property `Rates` is not a list. So assigning `rateList` to `Rates` is not allowed.

Comment: Rates property on your MyRoot class is not a List, can you edit your question?

Comment: You've defined `MyRoot.Rates` as a `public MyRates` but you're attempting to assign to it a `List<MyRates>`.  I don't think the compiler will let you get very far with that.

Comment: also the thing is that you have access to your myRoot object, why you ask about your root object instead the filtering just the collection inside? do you want a new object or do you have a collection or myRoots objects too?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, I think you need to change your model to create Rates property as a List of MyRates, and add the property Program too

```
public class MyRoot
    {
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public List<MyRates> Rates { get; set; }
    }

public class MyRates
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Rate { get; set;}
    public string Program { get; set; }
}
```

and here is like the Main method should look

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rateList = new List<MyRates>()
            {
                new MyRates {Type = "A", Program = "ABC", Rate = "1.0"},
                new MyRates {Type = "B", Program = "DEF", Rate = "1.5"},
                new MyRates {Type = "B", Program = "XYZ", Rate = "2.5"},
            };

            var myRoot = new MyRoot { LastUpdated = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-09"), Rates = rateList };

            var list = rateList.Where(x => x.Type == "B");

            //OR try to create a new object
            myRoot = new MyRoot {LastUpdated = myRoot.LastUpdated, Rates = myRoot.Rates.Where(x => x.Type == "B").ToList() };


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFilteredList = rateList.Where(x=> x.Type == "B");
```

thats it. The Where is a lambda expression which returns anything in the collection that has Type = B.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myRoot = new MyRoot { RatesAsOf = "2016-11-09", Rates = ratesList.Where(r=>r.Type == "B") };
```

You really need to read up on LINQ. This is basic stuff.

Comment: Rates is not a list, this won't work until the OP fixes his model.

Comment: Good catch. I've also noticed that his MyRoot class has no property called RatesAsOf. All sorts of issues with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

var myRoot = new MyRoot { RatesAsOf = "2016-11-09", Rates = ratesList };

var myRoot1 = new MyRoot { LastUpdated = myRoot.LastUpdated, Rates =  myRoot.Rates.Where(x => x.Type == "A").ToList() };